# After injecting dependency still facing same issue please guide me

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Shiv%20Data%20Records/IDEs/IDE/sts-4.8.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/D:/Shiv%20Data%20Records/IDEs/IDE/sts-4.8.0.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Shiv%20Data%20Records/IDEs/IDE/sts-4.8.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/D:/Shiv%20Data%20Records/IDEs/IDE/sts-4.8.0.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` Please run this command and remove or exclude duplicate dependency from pom.xml

Comment: check from which dependency SLF4J is redundant !